# How to create a custom monolog file only for users login in symfony

Tags: php, symfony, monolog

I need implement a simple log system for users. In the bundle actions of users (for example), i would like to use monolog with some samples like this.

```
public function indexAction(){
        $logger = $this->get('logger');
        $logger->users('User {X} is logout');
}
```

And it log, saves in specific file this log (users.log) for example

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can achieve this with a channels.

The custom channel could be created (in this case `user_channel`). The handler `user_handler` is created that only log records for the `user_channel`. In controller the specific logger for a channel is requested. Everything that is logged with this logger will go to `user_channel`. `user_handler` will put only that messages to the log file.

```
# app/config/config.yml
monolog:
    channels: ['user_channel']
    handlers:
        user_handler:
            level:    debug
            type:     stream
            path:     '%kernel.logs_dir%/user.log'
            channels: ['user_channel']
        main:
            level:    debug
            type:     stream
            path:     '%kernel.logs_dir%/log.log'
            channels: ['!user_channel'] #In case you don't want other handler to receive user_channel messages
```

Then in controller you can directly access the log handler.

```
public function indexAction(){
        $logger = $this->get('monolog.logger.user_channel');
        $logger->debug('User {X} is logout');
}
```

The log entity will be written to `'%kernel.logs_dir%/user.log'`.